# Mocking nested service classes with many dependencies

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a bunch of service classes that all pretty much look like this, or similar.

```java
@Service
public class ServiceA {
   private RepositoryA repA;
   private RepositoryB repB;
   private DependencyC depC;
   private DependencyD depD;
   private ServiceB serviceB;

   @Autowired
   public ServiceA(RepositoryA repA, RepositoryB repB, DependencyC depC, DependencyD depD, ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.repA = repA;
        ....
   }
}
```

Now I want to use those services in my test classes without booting up Spring. If I use the beans inside the application context, the tests take too long. I want to mock the service classes but I don't know how because of the deeply nested structure. The easy way would be to mock all repositories, dependencies and services used by ServiceA and inject them myself inside the test class but that doesn't seem right since I would have to do the same thing with ServiceB.

Comment: Why would you need to do that with `ServiceB`? That should be a mock as well for this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mockito for this, then your code will be similar to this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ServiceATest {

   @Mock
   RepositoryA repA;

   @Mock
   RepositoryB repB;

   @Mock
   DependencyC depC;

   @Mock
   DependencyD depD;

   @Mock
   ServiceB serviceB;

   @InjectMocks
   ServiceA serviceA;
}
```

Then, when you need to use mocks in your test, you mock methods of you mocked classes, for example:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
  ...
  when(repA.repMethod()).thenReturn(new SomeObject());
  
  SomeObject mockedObject = serviceA.serviceMethod(); // if serviceMethod call repMethod, you will get the object which you passed in youк mock method call
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple choices:

1. mock `ServiceB` too
2. do what you described, since you're going to do that anyway in order to write tests for `ServiceB` so you can reuse that work
3. build an alternative Spring context full of mocks and use that for testing

I usually go with 2. It's impure because the correctness of `ServiceA` depends on the correctness of `ServiceB`, but it's less testing code to write, manage, and understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServiceATest {
   private RepositoryA repA;
   private RepositoryB repB;
   private DependencyC depC;
   private DependencyD depD;
   private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Before
    public void init() { 
    this.repB = mock(RepositoryA.class);
     .....
    // mock all repositories you need.
    this.serveceB = new ServiceB(repoB,...);
    //then use contructor method to instantiate serviceB. Also do same with 
    //serviceB 
    this.serviceA = new ServiceA(repA,  repB,depC, depD, serviceB)
    }



     //Write the tests like that

     @Test
     public void saveanything_shouldBeCorect() {
     when(repoA.save()any()).thenReturn(mySavedMock);
     MyVariable resp = serviceA.save(myMock);
     // them assert your resp.
     }
    

}
```

The important thing is to use the mockito method "when (rep.anython (any ())) only in the repositories that you have moved to the init method.